# Install Microsoft SUA in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, nfs

Is there a way to install Microsoft Subsystem for UNIX Applications in Windows 8 Pro (I know it is included in W8 Enterprise). I need to mount NFS shares and would rather not rely on 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. Also the Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications is deprecated In Windows 8. So use 3rd party tools.

Comment: But isn't it included in the Windows 8 Enterprise versions?

Comment: yes, but removed in 8.1 update. And the feature is only available in the Enterprise, so you can't install it in Pro.